# Warning: Attempt to present View Controller on whose view is not in the hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c

Trying to present a new view controller as in below code, but I get the warning

"Attempt to present  on whose view is not in the window hierarchy"

*`Warning: Attempt to present <ActivityViewController: 0x7fb6225ca8a0> on <ViewController: 0x7fb62254cb50> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`*

```
-(IBAction) loginUser:(id)sender {

NSString *userEmail = _emailTxt.text;
NSString *userPassword = _password.text;
ActivityViewController *activities = [[ActivityViewController alloc] init];

NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [DataAccessLayer context];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SignupInfo" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email == %@", userEmail];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"email" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if(result.count > 0) {
    NSManagedObject *fetchedsignupInfo = (NSManagedObject *)[result objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *storedUserEmail = [fetchedsignupInfo valueForKey:@"email"];
    NSString *storedPassword = [fetchedsignupInfo valueForKey:@"password"];
    if(([userEmail length] == 0) || ([userPassword length] == 0))
    {
        // Error to enter Email or Password
        [self displayAlertMessage:@"Email or Password are required"];
    } else if (![userEmail isEqualToString:storedUserEmail] || ![userPassword isEqualToString:storedPassword]) {
        // Error - Wrong email or password entered
        [self displayAlertMessage:@"Wrong email or password entered"];
    } else if ( [userEmail isEqualToString:storedUserEmail] && [userPassword isEqualToString:storedPassword]) {
        // Login Successful
        //[self.navigationController presentViewController:activities animated:YES];

        [self presentViewController:activities animated:YES completion:nil];            
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It appears that `self` is some other view controller. And the error would indicate that `self` is not currently being displayed. You can't present a view controller from another view controller that isn't itself already displayed.

Comment: And update your question with the complete error, not a summary of the error.

Comment: That is the warning I am getting ..self is a view controller on login screen which is a first screen

Comment: So the code you posted is from your `ViewController` class. `ViewController` hasn't been displayed. That is why you get the error when `ViewController` (which isn't displayed) tries to display the `ActivityViewController`..

Comment: How come View Controller has not been displayed? My first screen is login screen where user inputs credentials and click login, that should take him to screen representing ActivityViewController, this error is happening when user clicks login

Comment: Are you mistakenly creating a second instance of `ViewController`?

Comment: I don't think ...so is it possible that I have a segue for modal and I am also trying to present ActivityViewController programmatically?

Comment: I removed the segue and now I don't get error, but my new view controller is blank black screen after clicking login